# Quadrilateral- other angles

Tags: geometry

Given all four angles of a quadrilateral $ABCD$, the fact that $AC$ bisects angle $A$, and that angles $A$ and $B$ are equal,  how do we find $ACD$, $ADB$, $ABD$, $CBD$? Better yet, is there a formula for each of those angles in terms of angles $A, B, C, D$?

Answer (score 1):

We can certainly **compute** all the angles mentioned. In principle, the computation procedure described below yields a formula. It is not a formula I would care to write down, but it can be done explicitly for use, say, in a computer program. There may be *nice* formulas for the various angles. This answer does not address that.

The fact that the angles at $A$ and $B$ are equal does not play a role in the calculation. It may be important in seeking nice formulas.

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $AC=1$. We know $\angle DAC$ (it is half of the angle at $A$). We also know the angle at $D$. So $\angle ACD$ is known, since the angles of $\triangle ACD$ have sum $180^\circ$.

In $\triangle ACD$, we know all the angles and one side $AC$. So by the Sine Law, we know the sides $AD$ and $CD$.

Similarly, we can find the sides $AB$ and $BC$. And by the Cosine Law we can find $BD$.

Now for example for $\triangle ABD$, we know all the sides, so we can find the two unknown angles by using the Cosine Law. Similarly, we can find any other of the angles mentioned in the OP.

Comment: EDIT: I added an extra condition. I think that the information is now sufficient.